# loosing internet connectivity after some time in ubuntu 22.04 running with low latency kernel

Tags: networking, 22.04

I have 5 interfaces on this system

```
enp1s0f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
    inet 192.168.20.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.20.255
    inet6 fe80::b37:905f:587b:c38b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 50:7c:6f:53:e6:f4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 20210  bytes 1338227 (1.3 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 51565  bytes 3291831 (3.2 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0 
enp1s0f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 50:7c:6f:53:e6:f5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp1s0f2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 50:7c:6f:53:e6:f6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp1s0f3: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 50:7c:6f:53:e6:f7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.33.42.122  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.33.42.255
    inet6 fe80::edbc:d5a5:8239:1b2e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether d8:5e:d3:6c:34:67  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 10084  bytes 10471053 (10.4 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 25  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 5362  bytes 510217 (510.2 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 318  bytes 69158 (69.1 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 318  bytes 69158 (69.1 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have connected to external network using enp4s0 and running an application on interface enp1s0f0. I have created 2 vfs on enp1s0f0 and using ice driver for those interfaces. After some time I see that I loose internet connectivity and connectivity to external network on enp4s0. I am using linux-lowlatency kernel on these system. This behavior is same on a different PC with similar configuration. Is anyone else facing the same issue with ubuntu 22.04LTS systems. If yes, can anyone help me on how I can fix this.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.